# Slow DNS with Realtek 8111/8168/8411

Tags: networking, drivers, dns, realtek

Since 1 or 2 months I have a very annoying issue with my wired network connection.

I have a Asus motherboard with a Realtek 8111/8168/8411 network adapter.
But I have the same issue with a Intel Gigabit-CT-Desktop-Adapter PCI Express.

I am sure I didn't had these issues 2 - 6 months ago.

Almost every website I want to go to waits 2 - 30 seconds and is then loaded very fast. Speedtest give me good results.

I have the same issues with ping, it waits a bit with no output and then starts pinging.

Nslookup on the other hand is very fast.

I already changed my IP and DNS settings.

I have these issues with Ubuntu 16.04, Ubuntu 16.10, KDE Neon 16, Antegros, Solus and OpenSuse Tumbleweed.

If you need more infos just ask me, I will add them to this post.
Thanks!

Comment: I wonder if you ever found any resolution with this. I experience a very similar problem both on Ubuntu and Pop OS 22.04. It seems like poor DNS performance. In Ubuntu the problem went away when I connected to my work VPN, but that's not helping in Pop OS. I haven't been able to try the alternative drivers yet because I wiped and installed Pop OS when it seemed like the problem wasn't there booting from Live USB, but it's shown back up. This is on symmetrical gigabit connection and other devices on the network don't have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, bandwidth (speedtest) and ping time (ping) are not the same thing.

1) how many ms do you see in ping output? Also where do you ping? You have to ping to a nearby address (eg. to your home router 192.168.X.X) and then another one far away from you (like google.com) so you can compare the results to see if there is an internal home/office network issue or bad internet connection ISP, etc.

2) have you tried using manual DNS servers? eg. 8.8.8.8
Do you see any difference?

It sounds to me more router settings issue, than anything else. But without further information it is hard to guess...

Comment: 1.My ping to facebook.com is around 60ms. Google.com takes ~20ms.
But thats not the problem. The problem is even before it starts pinging.
It loads 5 seconds and then the line "PING facebook.com (31.13.83.36) 56(84) bytes of data" appears. When I ping 31.13.83.36 it starts imminently.

2. Yeah my current DNS is 8.8.4.4

Comment: And everything works fine under window.

Comment: I tried driver r8169 and r8168.